# How to calculate APR on asset appreciation

Tags: apr

When I search for APR calculators, I only find mortgage and credit repayment calculators.

I am looking for the opposite. I want to calculate APR on asset appreciation.

I bought something for $15.k in 1993 and it is now estimated at between $31 and $42k. How do I calculate what the APR return on investment is?

Is there a formula? An online calculator? How would I do it in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 25 years, the asset went from 15 to 31-42.

```
(31/15)^(1/25)= 1.02946 or 2.946% CAGR
(42/15)^(1/25)= 1.04204 or 4.204% CAGR
```

Of course, a CAGR to 3 decimal places is absurd when your asset value has a value of $36.5+/- 15%.

Looking at the numbers I'd have guessed "3-4%/yr" 
The notation I used is what you'd plug into a spreadsheet, FYI.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. That's great. If I can find something paying more, then I will see the asset, else retain it.

Comment: No problem! Keep in mind, this question may be a duplicate, and members may vote to close. I am on my cell phone and can't easily search.

Comment: It didn't look like a duplicate when I searched.